# Add image source to HTML using C# variable

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm trying to use a the url from a template field in Sitecore7 as a variable and then add that to the src attribute on an image.  I've tried the following two methods and neither return correctly.

Method 1:

```
var url = communityHeader.LeftLogo.MediaUrl;
LeftLogo2.Attributes.Add("src",url);
```

Method 2:

```
var url - communityHeader.LeftLogo.MediaUrl;
LeftLogo2.Attributes["src"]=url;
```

Neither are returning the url in the source, just an empty src attribute.

Comment: When is this code running? Maybe the object has already been rendered to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url - communityHeader.LeftLogo.MediaUrl;
LeftLogo2.Attributes["src"]=url;
```

Are you actually running that exact code? Note that you have a single '-' instead of '='. You should be able to access the src attribute in this manner.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that exact code (with the = correct) and it returns: <img id="LeftLogo2" itemprop="logo" alt="Logo" src="">

Comment: Perhaps try hard coding the value to see if your issue is with the variable.

IE
LeftLogo2.Attributes["src"] = "test";

Run that, and respond if it's still an empty value

Comment: Yes, that returned: <img src="Presentation/Sublayouts/Community/test" id="LeftLogo2" itemprop="logo" alt="Logo"> I have verified that the variable is in string format - not sure why it won't return?

Comment: So the problem is where your 'communityHeader.LeftLogo.MediaUrl' is being assigned. Can you set a breakpoint after you assign it and ensure it's value is as you're expecting? 

We've determined 'LeftLogo2.Attributes["src"]=url;' is definitely the correct way to assign the value, so the problem starts further back in the code. Would you be willing to provide more source code context?

Comment: Yes - you are correct. I've been able to determine the variable is empty and am going to enlist the help of a Sitecore professional.